# Iron Router not working like expected

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I play a bit around with Iron Router ([Tutorial](http://meteortips.com/tutorial/iron-router-part-1/)) but my templates don't work correct.

html:

```
<head>
  <title>MY TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
</body>

<template name="hello">
  This is the hello template.
</template>
<template name="home">
  This is the home template.
</template>
```

JS

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.route('hello');
    this.route('home', {path: '/'} );
});
```

When I start meteor it renders the title in the head-section correctly but it is not showing any content from my templates in the body-section. Meteor is not throwing any errors but in the browser console I have 6 Errors:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Template.__create__')
    (anonyme Funktion) (iron-dynamic-template.js, line 416)
    (anonyme Funktion) (iron-dynamic-template.js, line 433)
    global code (iron-dynamic-template.js, line 440)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Parent.prototype')
    _inherits (meteor.js, line 220)
    (anonyme Funktion) (iron-layout.js, line 150)
    (anonyme Funktion) (iron-layout.js, line 487)
    global code (iron-layout.js, line 494)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Iron.Layout({template: this.options.layoutTemplate})')
    constructor (iron-router.js, line 1475)
    (anonyme Funktion) (iron-router.js, line 1771)
    (anonyme Funktion) (iron-router.js, line 1784)
    global code (iron-router.js, line 2356)
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Package['iron-router'].RouteController')
    global code (global-imports.js, line 3)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Template
    (anonyme Funktion) (template.bla.js, line 2)
    global code (template.bla.js, line 20)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Router
    (anonyme Funktion) (bla.js, line 1)
    global code (bla.js, line 6)
```

anyone have a clue whats wrong?

Comment: Your errors are mainly undefined symbols, are you sure you added the `iron:router` package correctly ? `meteor add iron:router`

Comment: I hope so. I just installed meteorite via `npm`. In the new meteor project i just installed iron-router via `mrt add iron-router`. The install-log tells me everything was fine.

Comment: What you should have done is: `meteor add iron:router`. From your error logs it looks like you're using an outdated version.

Comment: ok I should read comments better next time. It works now. thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the same Problem:

the answer is to NOT install iron router via meteorite. It seems like iron-router is now a smart package and you can add it now out of the box via meteor.

CORRECT
Install iron-router via:

```
meteor add iron:router
```

WRONG (deprecated):

```
mrt add iron-router
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check your version first then update. Your error comes from library.

```
meteor remove iron:router
meteor update
meteor add iron:router
```